# Crashes from instanton.sys

Tags: bsod, crash, lenovo-laptop

My new Lenovo X1 Yoga laptop (with Windows 10 Anniversary update) occasionally crashes - a Blue-Screen-of-Death appears, saying at the bottom `what failed: InstantOn.sys`. I found `C:\Program Files\Lenovo\InstantOn\InstantOn.sys` (version 3.0.0.0, dated to 10/14/2015), so it's some Lenovo driver, probably powering their [Splashtop-based InstantOn mini-OS](https://www.cnet.com/news/lenovo-announces-netbook-with-splashtop-instant-on-technology/).

1. Is there an updated, non-crashing version of this driver?
   [Searching for `Lenovo InstantOn download`](https://www.google.com/search?q=lenovo+instanton+download) show me that there used to be a download called `giui10ww.exe`, but I can't find any recent version of it.
2. I don't really care about this mini-OS, so how can I just disable the whole thing? I know I could stop the driver form loading by running `sc config InstantOn start= disabled`, but I'm concerned some other parts of this system would break even further.

Comment: hve you installed all drivers from Lenovos website? http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/ThinkPad-X-Series-laptops/ThinkPad-X1-Yoga-Type-20FQ-20FR?linkTrack=linkTrack%253ADS_page%2BSystemUpdate&tabName=Downloads&beta=false

Comment: I couldn't find any relevant driver (by name). I didn't go through the entire huge collection...

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I uninstalled by running `C:\Program Files\Lenovo\InstantOn\unins000.exe` - said "do you want to uninstall Lenovo EasySomething", and then the problem was gone. As always, YMMV

Answer (score -1):

I found a description of instanton.sys at https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/X240-and-X240s-new-software-Lenovo-InstantOn-Beta/m-p/1295809?page=1:

"... The software is called Lenovo InstantOn Beta and here's how it works:  Today, Windows 8 running on laptops, by default, goes to Sleep mode when the lid is closed.  This causes your programs to stop running, and your internet/VPN connection is dropped.  What InstantOn does, is change the meaning of the lid close action "Sleep".  Instead of immediately going to sleep mode when the lid is closed, InstantOn will make the system stay awake for 1 hour.  During this hour, the CPU is set to minimum speed, and the speakers/microphone/touchpad/LCD are turned off.  However your network connection and apps stay alive, they just run at a very slow speed.  InstantOn mode uses more battery than the system in Sleep mode, but less than the system that is simply idle without InstantOn.  The goal is to make a laptop behave more like a tablet (e.g. connected standby) where it can be resumed instantly, at least for 1 hour.  Currently, the software is only supported on Windows 8, and only on X240/X240s.  The software requires special BIOS support that only exists in these 2 systems.  If you have X240/X240s, and try it, let me know how it works for you.  Thanks!"

Oh dear, this is quite a worry for me, as I try to mitigate the fire-hazard of my BSOD-prone ThinkPad 13 Gen 2.  My current workarounds are 1) to disable the "advanced sleep" mode (using powercfg.exe /h off), 2) to remove all of the ways (e.g. lid-closing) that it might sleep or hibernate, and (most importantly) 3) to set its "Turn off the display" timer to "Never".  In particular: if its display goes dark for more than 30 seconds, then my laptop reliably enters a BSOD -- sometimes with the CPU running hot and the fan running at full speed, i.e. a significant fire-hazard.  The mention of BIOS support by this Lenovo engineer makes me concerned that, even without instanton.sys being loaded (and it's not being loaded at boot-time, according to ntbtlog.txt), the BIOS on my laptop may still have a "feature" which makes it responsive to hardware events for an hour after it was put to sleep.  Sigh.